# Insert update mysql table values alternatively using php

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

I have table TB1 , i want to insert or update values into this table. If i have three values (3,4,5) means I need to insert 1P_id , 2P_id and count alternatively if values are exist i need to update count value as plus one from current value in this table.  help to find that query logic using php.

Comment: there's an `ON DUPLICATE` clause you can use: `INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (val1, val2, val3) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE val1 = val1 + 1;`. In this case you need constraints as well. I guess `1P_id` and `2P_id` should be unique

Comment: Before insert validate whether exists or not in db.....

Comment: yes , it works fine @Royal Bg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to do this would be in a single INSERT with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE query.

Example structure:

```
INSERT INTO table ... VALUES .... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

Answer (score 0):

first make sure if there is the values exist  :

```
$val1 = 2;
$val2 = 3;
$count = 5;

$sql="select * from `test_table` where 1P_id =$val1 AND 2P_id =$val2 AND count=$count";
$rs=mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_fetch_rows() > 1) {  
    // run update query
} else {
    //run insert query
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php

$val1 = 3; // as we assume for 1P_id;
$val2 = 2; // as we assume for 2P_id;

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `your_table` WHERE 1P_id='$val1' AND 2P_id='$val2' LIMIT 1 ") or die(mysql_error());
if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //update the row
    $id = $row['id'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE `your_table` SET count=count+1 WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1 ") or die(mysql_error());
} else {
    // INSERT the row
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `your_table`(1P_id, 2P_id, count) VALUES('$val1', '$val2', 1)") or die(mysql_error());
}  

?>
```